# Getting waaay too many "Spawning Local" fastcgi messages

Tags: python, fastcgi, lighttpd

I've got Lighttpd running 7 Python apps via fastcgi on an Ubuntu server. I turned on fastcgi debugging in the Lighttpd configuration and noticed something very weird in the logs:

Normally, when you start up Lighttpd/fastcgi you get a message in the logs that says something like:

```
2009-10-07 09:21:53: (mod_fastcgi.c.1365) --- fastcgi spawning local
        proc: /etc/lighttpd/scripts/my_fcgi_script_name.py
        port: 0
        socket /var/www/.handles/my_site_name.socket
        min-procs: 1
        max-procs: 1
2009-10-07 09:21:53: (mod_fastcgi.c.1390)
        port: 0
        socket /var/www/.handles/my_site_name.socket
        current: 0 / 1
```

As I said, though, I've got seven different apps running through Lighttpd. I'd expect seven of those messages.

Instead, I'm getting 49 of them! It looks like it's going through loading all 7 scripts once for each script (7x7=49). I've tried removing one (so there are 6) and I get 36 log messages.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score -1):

> Instead, I'm getting 49 of them! It looks like it's going through loading all 7 scripts once for each script (7x7=49). I've tried removing one (so there are 6) and I get 36 log messages.

Empirically speaking, you've found the reason. Debugging logs tend to be very verbose.